# When I subtract memory addresses, why is the result smaller than I expected?

Tags: c++, c

I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    int a;
    float b;
} x[10], *p1, *p2;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    p1 = &x[1];
    p2 = &x[5];

    int i = p2 - p1;

    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

I can visualize `X`'s layout in memory, 10 boxes containing an `int` and a `float`, `p1` will point at the beginning of the second box (`x[1]`) and `p2` pointing at the beginning of the 6th box (`x[5]`):

```
   X   0   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
       _______________________________
    b  |__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
    a  |__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
          |           |    
          |           | 
          p1          p2
```

Is my drawing correct ? If so why is the result of `i` 4 ?
Having some difficulties understanding subtraction of two addresses ?

Comment: You tagged this question `c`, but you use `cout` in your example, which is C++ instead. Which are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I guess its a C question, but I used cout for simplicity I guess.

Comment: @DanielPryden It won't make a difference in the answer, will it?

Comment: @DanielPryden: It seems like code is written in MSVS. Sadly, people starting from there usually think that they program in "Visual C++" language. I've added C++ tag, but left C tag as well, because I feel like memory layout of structures covered in question applies to both.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is the same for both C and C++. But my knowledge of the C++ standard is admittedly spotty, and so I thought it would be worthwhile to add a tag for C++ to attract more C++ experts to the question. But I didn't want to re-tag without confirming first that the C++ use was intentional. No worries.

Comment: why do people keep asking about operations 99% at a time are not needed, confusing or make code absolutely unmaintainable... just wondering...

Comment: @Bort, they ask so that in the 1 percent of the time they *are* needed, they can be used properly. Confusing and unmaintainable things are *exactly* what people should be encouraged to ask questions about, or else they're just going to continue to be confusing and unmaintainable, and then where would we be?

Comment: Maybe, but even in the 1% case where you could do such things as here in the example, you still could write more readable less confusing code and let the compiler do this exact optimization for you. Anyways.. I don't want to argue that this certainly helps understanding pointer arithmetic in arrays... so be it.

Comment: pointer arithmetic is done in units of the pointer type, not in units of bytes (so in this case there's 4 ints between the 2 addresses)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is how [pointer arithmetic](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc03ptarith.htm) works. Consider:

```
p1 = (x*)100;   // invalid memory address, just an example!
p2 = p1 + 1;
```

At this point, `p2` will not have the value `101`, but rather `100 + sizeof(x)` (which let's say is 8, so 108). It has been incremented not by one, but by one multiple of `sizeof(x)`! Conversely, subtracting an integer from a pointer actually subtracts *multiples of `sizeof(the pointed to type)`*.

So now if you do `int diff = p2 - p1`, you would certainly expect to get `1` back, not `8`! Otherwise, subtracting the number you just added would not yield the original value. Therefore, subtracting one pointer from another yields not the difference in memory addresses but the number of elements between the two pointers.

Moreover, the standard mandates that *pointer subtraction is meaningless unless the two pointers point to elements in the same array* (more correctly, it's undefined behavior and you are also allowed to use a pointer to "one past the last element" even if there is no such object there).

Finally, what if the compiler does not know the size of the pointed to type (i.e. the pointers are `void*`)? In this case, pointer arithmetic is not allowed at all. For example:

```
void* p = 100;
void* x = p + 1; // does not compile¹
```

¹ Some compilers may provide pointer arithmetic on `void*` as an [extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html) to the language specification. In this case this statement can indeed compile and the result would depend on the specification of said extension (e.g. gcc would end up with the value 101).

Comment: Nice explanation, but your example will compile, albeit with warnings as-is. What I believe is specifically prohibited is adding two pointers, i.e. if you tried to add p and x after that.

Comment: @DanFego: Thank you for catching this and allowing me to learn something new (I am not very experienced in C, as in "some of the finer points of where C and C++ differ"). I have updated the answer with an explanation of what happens here.

Comment: Actually, pointer substraction is meaningless unless the two pointers point to elements in the same declared object, that need not be an array. They can also be, for example, pointers to elements to the same structure.

Comment: @rodrigo: You 'll have to qualify that a little. For example, the C++03 standard clearly states (5.7-6): *Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: pointer arithmetic on `void*` is a [gcc extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html). It is not allowed in either C89 or C99.

Comment: @Jon Oh, you are right! That happens for not checking my assumed knowledge. What is allowed with pointers to the same declared object is _comparing_ the pointers, not _substracting_ them. Also C99 specs, under appendix J.2-Undefined behavior, it enums _Pointers that do not point into, or just beyond, the same array object are subtracted_. Indeed, you learn something every day.

Comment: @pmg: Well, it's good to know that my initial notion was not quite wrong and even better to learn exactly what happened there. I 've improved the answer and included your link. Thank you.