# Difference between the address of adjacent array elements..?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am just confused with the output which I got for the following code :

```
int arr[] = {10,20,30};
cout<<&arr[1]<<"\t"<<&arr[0]<<"\t"<<&arr[1] - &arr[0];
```

the output which I got was like

```
0046F7A0    0046F79C    1
```

I want to know why the difference between the address gave 1 ( I expected 4)...?
Is it something to do with pointer subtraction..?

Comment: might be dubplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357151/when-i-subtract-memory-addresses-why-is-the-result-smaller-than-i-expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is the result of [pointer arithmetic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Additive_operators). This is the same reason why `arr + 1` would point to `arr[1]`. Pointer arithmetic is only well-defined when both pointers point to elements in the same array. If two such pointers, `P` and `Q`, point to array locations `i` and `j`, then `P-Q = i-j`.

Also, if you look at the differences of the actual addresses printed, they match your expectations - the difference is `4`.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, this has to do with pointer arithmetic. Subtracting two `int` pointers gives you the difference between them measured in `sizeof (int)` units. You can get the difference in plain bytes by casting your pointers to `char` pointers, as `char`s are guaranteed to be of size 1.

```
uint arr[] = {10,20,30};
cout << &arr[1] << "\t" << &arr[0] << "\t" << (char*)&arr[1] - (char*)&arr[0];
```

Output:

```
0x23fe44        0x23fe40        4
```

Answer (score -1):

`0046F7A0 - 0046F79C` is actually `4` but  `&arr[0]-&arr[1] = (0046F7A0 - 0046F79C)/sizeof(int= 4 bytes)` because subtracting two pointers gives you the number of elements between them.